# Hive - Fastest way to retrieve partitions and file locations

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

If i understood it correctly, the partition and physical location ( path of the file ) may differ.
I need to retrieve file location, and then its partitions.

I tried to use following:

```
private String addLocation(String partition) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^hdfs://(.*?))/");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(partition);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String location = partition.replace(matcher.group(1), "");
        location = location.substring(0, location.lastIndexOf("/"));
        return location;
    }

    return "";
}


// table name is in format <db>.<tableName>
String table = tableName.split("\\.")[1]; 
Map<String,String> partitionMap = new HashMap<>();
String sql1 = "select distinct INPUT__FILE__NAME from " + tableName + " where " + partitionSpec;
ResultSet rs1 = executeQuery(sql1);

while (rs1.next()) {
    String partition_path = addLocation(rs1.getString("input__file__name"));
    String partitionString = Arrays.stream(partition_path.substring(partition_path.indexOf(table))
            .split("/"))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    partitionMap.put(partitionString,partition_path);
}


return partitionMap;
```

using this i was assuming the returned INPUT_FILE_NAME would be always in format of

```
hdfs://<nameService>/..../<table>/partition1=../partition2=../file1.txt
```

But i found out this may not be true at all, and for example table would not be present in the path at all as the physical location differs.

So i created different approach:

```
   private String getPartitionsFromTable(String tableName) throws SQLException {
        String columntQuery = "describe " + tableName;
        ResultSet columnResult = executeQuery(columntQuery);
        List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean isPartition = false;
        while (columnResult.next()) {

            String column = columnResult.getString("col_name");
            if (column.startsWith("#") && column.contains("Partition ")) {
                isPartition = true;
            }

            if (isPartition) {
                if (!column.isEmpty() && !column.startsWith("#")) {
                    columns.add(column);
                }
            }
        }

        return String.join(",", columns);
    }


  String columnQuery = getPartitionsFromTable(tableName);
  String sql1 = "select distinct " + columnQuery + ", INPUT__FILE__NAME from " + tableName + " where " + partitionSpec;
  ResultSet rs1 = executeQuery(sql1);
```

This way, this actually return physical location ( INPUT_FILE_NAME), and value of the partition columns.

The problem with this that while it does return correct results all the time, no matter the structure in hive ( the problem with the first approach - it didn't work with any structure ), but it is super slow if there is a lot of data.

My question is, is there any better, more optimized approach for this issue, is there a way to make it faster?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Querying the metastore directly rather than via Hive might give you the information you need

Comment: @OneCricketeer would you mind to elaborate please?

Comment: The metastore is the traditional DBMS that stores partition and table metadata. If you've ever had missing partitions, then needed to run `msck repair`, it compares the metastore to what's in filesystem. My point was that rather than making a jdbc connection with Hive, you could instead maybe try to use the metastore